Snackbar state not updating problem nuxt js
The problem that i am encountering is related to the fact that i moved my project from Vue to Nuxt . The problem that i am stuck at now is a snackbar . I have a snackbar component
<template>
  <v-snackbar v-model="snackbar" :timeout="timeout" :color="color">
    {{ message }}
  </v-snackbar>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, watch } from 'vue';
import { useUserStore } from '~/store/user';

const store = useUserStore()

const snackbar = ref(false);
const message = ref('');
const timeout = ref(3000);
const color = ref('error');

console.log("STORE SNACKBAR" , store.snackbarVisible)
console.log("STORE SNACKBAR mesage" , store.snackbarMessage)


// Watch the Pinia store for changes
watch(
  () => store.snackbarVisible,
  (newVal) => {
    console.log("newval " , newVal)
    console.log(store.snackbarVisible)
    snackbar.value = newVal;
    console.log("IN SNACLBAR " , snackbar)
    if (newVal) {
      message.value = store.snackbarMessage;
      console.log("IN SNACKMAR MEESATE ", message.value)
    }
  }
);
</script>


I have my Pinia store which updated the snackbar:
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

export const useUserStore = defineStore('user', {
  state: () => ({
    auth: false,
    admin: false,
    snackbarMessage: '',
    snackbarVisible: false
  }),
  getters: {
    isAuthenticated:state => state.auth === true ,
    isAdmin: state => state.admin === true,
    isSnackBarVisible: state => state.snackbarVisible === true
  },
  actions: {
    initializeAuth() {
      this.auth = useCookie('userLoggedIn').value === 1;
      this.admin = useCookie('admin').value === 1;
    },
    setUser(user) {
      this.auth = user.auth;
      this.admin = user.admin;
    },
    showSnackbar(message) {
      this.snackbarMessage = message;
      this.snackbarVisible = true;
      console.log("AICI IN STORE")
      console.log("SNACKBAR VISSBILE " , this.snackbarVisible)
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.snackbarMessage = '';
        this.snackbarVisible = false;
        console.log("SNACKBAR TERMINATED")
      }, 4000);
    }
  }
});


And i call the showSnackBar in my middleware
// middleware/auth.js
import { useUserStore } from "~/store/user";

export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async (to, from) => {
  const userStore = useUserStore()  // Adjust this if using Vuex or Pinia
  // de folosit set user 
  const isUserloggedInCookie =  useCookie('userLoggedIn')
  const isAdminloggedInCookie =  useCookie('admin')
 
  const user = {
    auth : isUserloggedInCookie.value === 1,
    admin : isAdminloggedInCookie.value === 1
  }
  userStore.setUser(user)
 
  const isAuth = userStore.isAuthenticated;

  if (!isAuth) {
    userStore.showSnackbar('You need to be logged in!');
    return navigateTo('/user/logout');
    
  }
});


These are the console.logs
// here the showSnackBar is called
AICI IN STORE
SNACKBAR VISSBILE  true
// This is in the SnackBar component
STORE SNACKBAR false
STORE SNACKBAR mesage 
// here is after the setTimeout function
SNACKBAR TERMINATED

Now i get redirected to the /user/logout , but no snackbar is displayed.
!!!
If i use router.push('/user/logout') instead of navigateTo everything works fine !
Would you be able to point to me what am i doing wrong or where my logic is mistaken ?

Do you need the middleware to be async here? If you do, maybe consider using await for the navigateTo part. Otherwise, using a client-side navigation is fine mostly.

I do not need async , but i tried to await for the navigateTo to go to the logout and the snackbar to load . As i said if i am using async , i do not get redirected to the logout , but the snackbar works .
